# there must be 9 combinations of booleans

Tags: boolean, logic, state, combinatorics

dont know if this is the correct stack exchange forum but i have the following puzzle

i have two booleans and they have 4 possible combinations

```
   X X
   X 0
   0 X
   0 0
```

2x2 = 4 , i thought

now i have three booleans, and i have those possible combinations

```
   X X X
   X X 0
   X 0 0
   0 0 0
   0 X X
   0 0 X
   X 0 X
   0 X 0
```

But there are only 8, i´m mentaly not able to find out the nineth combination,
is there one ?

please Help me im stuck and always thought 3x3 = 9

Comment: In the first case, it's `2^2=4`, in the second case it's `2^3=8`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about combinatorics and belongs to [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found all combinations. For each boolean you have 2 options. Combining 3 booleans you have 2 to the third power combinations, which equals 8.

So there is not a nineth combination.

This principle of combining options is the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product

Answer (score 1):

Your math is wrong.  it's 2 ^ 3, not 3 * 3

2 ^ 3 = 2 * 2 * 2 = 8

Comment: thank you very much i thought i´m too stupid :D